# Find and Replace text (FART): Replaced 0 occurence(s)

Tags: windows, command-line, find-and-replace

The great [FART](http://emtunc.org/blog/03/2011/farting-the-easy-way-find-and-replace-text/) utility seems to be the norm when trying to replace text on the windows command line.

However I can't get it to work as shown in the examples. My test file *test.txt*:

```
Images Here Images
ImagesWhateverImages
```

I now try this:

```
fart -r -i -p "test.txt" "Images"
```

and get:

```
Images Here Images
ImagesWhateverImages
Found 4 occurence(s) in 1 file(s).
```

Great! But when now trying to replace Images with Foo it won't work:

```
fart -r -i -p "test.txt" "Images" "foo"
--> Replaced 0 occurence(s) in 1 file(s).
```

Everyone seems to just do a `fart -r -i- p <filename> <string_to_replace> <replacement>` command and work with it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fart and rip? This is my new favorite software!

Comment: you can also just do `-rip` to make it clearer what you're trying to say

Comment: `perl -p -i -e 's/Image/foo/' test.txt` leaves you smelling nicer.

Comment: And requires me to install 32MB perl. Even though I like pie.

Comment: Also Powershell: `$filename = $args[0]
$search = $args[1]
$replace = $args[2]
(Get-Content $filename) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$search", "$replace"} | 
Set-Content $filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a trick question? FART's usage help *clearly* states that `-p` stands for "preview", so if you remove it the changes will actually be made.

(Also, `-r` isn't required if you're only dealing with a single file.)

Comment: My first good laugh today :]

Comment: Now that was an easy solution. No joke here, I used PowerShell anyways. Thanks for the find :-)